# Unity3d how can i instantiating an object and giving movement in a back direction(endles running game)

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

What i am trying to do is instantiating 7 tilemap forward and my player shouldn't move, tile's should move to the back. How can i do that any advice?
I tried giving a force like that: `go.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(0, 0, -speed, ForceMode.Impulse);`
or `go.transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime);` but didn't work. I think i need to try someting different for the instantiating but i couldn't figure it out, can someone please give me an advice?
**my code:**

```
private void Update()
    {
        if ((spawnZ - amnTilesOnScreen * tileLength) < playerTransform.position.z - safeZone)
        {
            
            SpawnTile();
            DeleteTile();
        }
        
    }
    private void SpawnTile(int prefabIndex = -1)
    {
        GameObject go;
        if (prefabIndex == -1)
        {
            go = Instantiate(tilePrefabs[RandomPrefabIndex()], Vector3.forward * spawnZ,Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            
        }
        else
        {
            go = Instantiate(tilePrefabs[prefabIndex], Vector3.forward * spawnZ, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        }
        
        go.transform.SetParent(transform); 
        go.transform.position = Vector3.forward * spawnZ;
        //go.transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime);


        spawnZ += tileLength; 
        //go.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(0, 0, -speed, ForceMode.Impulse);
        activeTiles.Add(go);
    }
    private void DeleteTile()
    {
        Destroy(activeTiles[0]);
        activeTiles.RemoveAt(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, just one hitch is preventing you from getting what you want:

You will need to call your move

```
go.transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

every update for each of your block objects. As it stands, you will only call the move once, during the spawn method. It seems like you already have a list of tiles to move, inside

```
activeTiles
```

So, working off of this list of active tiles your update method might look something like:

```
private void Update()
{
    // First move all the active tiles
    foreach (var tileObj in activeTiles) {
        tileObj.transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    // The, do any spawn or destroy operations on them if needed.
    if ((spawnZ - amnTilesOnScreen * tileLength) < playerTransform.position.z - safeZone)
    {
            
        SpawnTile();
        DeleteTile();
    }
        
}
```

You probably dont need the physics movement unless you have a reason why the "force" of the tiles is more important than their motion. Generally speaking, it is more efficient to move objects directly, while physics motion is more for when you are trying to create effects of collisions between different objects. In this case, since the road just moves no matter what, directly moving them as above is probably your best bet.

Also remember to remove your road objects from the active list when you destroy them, or you will get NullReferenceException when you try to run update on an object that no longer exists.